# Vagrant up executes inline script within wrong VM

Tags: vagrant

I need help fixing following Vagrant file as it behaves incorrectly.

For some reason Shell script is executed on Windows VM, instead of Linux one when executing vagrant up.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config_wglr|
  config_wglr.winrm.timeout =   3600
  config_wglr.winrm.retry_limit = 30
  config_wglr.winrm.retry_delay = 10
  config_wglr.vm.boot_timeout = 3600
  config_wglr.vm.define "WGLR" do |glw_runner|
    glw_runner.vm.box = "gusztavvargadr/docker-windows"
    glw_runner.vm.network "private_network", ip: "xxxx"
  end
  config_wglr.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "256"]
  end
end

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config_lglr|
  config_lglr.vm.box = "generic/rocky8"
  config_lglr.vm.hostname = "LGLR"
  config_lglr.vm.network "private_network", ip: "yyyy"
  # the boxes need to be accessible via password and username
  config_lglr.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    systemctl restart sshd
    SHELL
    config_lglr.vm.define "LGLR"
  # begin disable audio
  config_lglr.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--audio", "none"]
  end
  # end disable audio
end
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Log of behavior - executing shell script before linux vm even got up.

```
==> WGLR: Machine booted and ready!
==> WGLR: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> WGLR: Setting hostname...
==> WGLR: Waiting for machine to reboot...
==> WGLR: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> WGLR: Mounting shared folders...
    WGLR: /vagrant => C:/workdir/ansible-playbook-gitlabrunners
==> WGLR: Running provisioner: shell...
    WGLR: Running: inline PowerShell script
    WGLR: sed : The term 'sed' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
    WGLR: spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    WGLR: At C:\tmp\vagrant-shell.ps1:1 char:5
    WGLR: +     sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' ...
    WGLR: +     ~~~
    WGLR:     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sed:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    WGLR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    WGLR:
    WGLR: systemctl : The term 'systemctl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
    WGLR: program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    WGLR: At C:\tmp\vagrant-shell.ps1:2 char:5
    WGLR: +     systemctl restart sshd
    WGLR: +     ~~~~~~~~~
    WGLR:     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (systemctl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    WGLR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    WGLR:
==> LGLR: Importing base box 'generic/rocky8'...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

I've missed DO on define level thus scope was wrong.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).